# w3wp.exe application pool crashing every 5 minutes

Tags: iis, windows-server-2016, asp-classic

I had a classic ASP working site on Windows 2012. Everything worked ok. Since I moved it to 2016 machine (same DB, same files), w3wp.exe is crashing every few minutes ;-(

I did the dump and there seems to be this 2 errors every time there is a crash:

> In
>   w3wp__xxx.net(domain)(pool)__PID__8764__Date__06_06_2017__Time_05_57_31PM__204__Second_Chance_Exception_C0000374.dmp
>   the assembly instruction at ntdll!RtlReportCriticalFailure+89 in
>   C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll from Microsoft Corporation has caused a
>   corrupted heap exception (0xC0000374) when trying to perform an
>   unknown operation on memory location 0x00000000 on thread 48 Current
>   NTGlobalFlags value: 0x0

The second one

> A COM+ STA Activity Pileup has been detected in
>   w3wp__xxx.net(domain)(pool)__PID__8764__Date__06_06_2017__Time_05_57_31PM__204__Second_Chance_Exception_C0000374.dmp.
>   There is more than one activity bound to every COM+ STA ThreadPool
>   thread.

I think the first one is the problem one, if I look at the thread under it:

Thread 48 - System ID 9056

Entry point   msvcrt!_threadstartex  Create time   6.6.2017 17:53:57  Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:00.359  Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 00:00:00.343

This thread is making a database operation using ADO.

The call to MSADO15!CCONNECTION::EXECUTE originated from vbscript!IDispatchInvoke2+76

ntdll!RtlReportCriticalFailure+89  ntdll!RtlpReportHeapFailure+32  ntdll!RtlpLogHeapFailure+9f  ntdll!RtlFreeHeap+ac  AcLayers!NS_FaultTolerantHeap::APIHook_RtlFreeHeap+3f70  msvcr120!free+1a  msvcr120!__freetlocinfo+13e  msvcr120!_updatetlocinfoEx_nolock+40  msvcr120!__updatetlocinfo+5f  msvcr120!_LocaleUpdate::_LocaleUpdate+3e  msvcr120!_input_l+10f  msvcr120!vscan_fn+6a  msvcr120!sscanf+19  myodbc5w!SQLGetCursorNameW+22887  myodbc5w!SQLGetCursorNameW+23c13  myodbc5w!SQLGetCursorNameW+169f0  myodbc5w!SQLGetCursorNameW+16399  odbc32!SetStmtAttr+5d1  odbc32!SQLSetStmtAttrW+91  msdasql!CKagRowsetProps::SetODBCOptions+1cd  msdasql!CKagRowsetProps::FindCapableCC+575  msdasql!CImpICommandText::Execute+ddd  msado15!CConnection::Execute+b1 msado15!_ExecuteAsync+1da  msado15!ExecuteAsync+59  msado15!CQuery::Execute+fae  msado15!CCommand::_Execute+18a  msado15!CConnection::OpenRecordset+df  msado15!CConnection::ExecuteWithModeFlag+622  msado15!CConnection::Execute+67  msado15!CConnection::Invoke+de2d  vbscript!IDispatchInvoke2+76  vbscript!InvokeDispatch+4fa  vbscript!CScriptRuntime::RunNoEH+f79  vbscript!CScriptRuntime::Run+dc  vbscript!CScriptEntryPoint::Call+f3  vbscript!CSession::Execute+3a0  vbscript!COleScript::ExecutePendingScripts+14b  vbscript!COleScript::SetScriptState+62  asp!CActiveScriptEngine::TryCall+2e  asp!CActiveScriptEngine::Call+3d  asp!CallScriptFunctionOfEngine+58  asp!ExecuteRequest+159  asp!Execute+237  asp!CHitObj::ViperAsyncCallback+425  asp!CViperAsyncRequest::OnCall+7e  comsvcs!CSTAActivityWork::STAActivityWorkHelper+50  combase!EnterForCallback+142  combase!SwitchForCallback+1c6  combase!PerformCallback+b0  combase!CObjectContext::InternalContextCallback+10d  combase!CObjectContext::DoCallback+31  comsvcs!CSTAActivityWork::DoWork+175  comsvcs!CSTAThread::ProcessQueueWork+68  comsvcs!CSTAThread::WorkerLoop+173  msvcrt!_callthreadstartex+25  msvcrt!_threadstartex+61  kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+24  ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+2f  ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+1b

I can not figure out what does this mean... I use mysql 5.7 and myODBC, it is the same as on the old windows 2012.

It seems that ADo is failing or what? But not every time, as I have connections every second and the w3wp.exe is failing every few minutes, sometimes 3 times in a row, sometimes 20 minute without fail.

Can anybody share some ideas please, I'll have to go back to old server and I am quite desperate. Can the msado15.dll be broken on windows 2016? The files are ok, I checked with the windows shell file checker.

Is it possible to get a support from MS somehow? Free or payed...

Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem, thanx for the help. It wasn't my code... Oracle's myODBC since 5.3.4 is severly corrupted with heap memory problems ;-( Confirmed in a bug report from someone but Oracle doesn't fix it...

5.3.6 and up version produce this kind of problems, reverting to 2014 5.3.4 version and everything is OK again...

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you're dealing with a null pointer being passed to ADO.  You need to look at the places your code calls ADO and make sure none of the parameters are null:

```
set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
If rs is Nothing then
  Response.Write("We have a problem with rs")
  Exit Sub
endif
If conn is Nothing then
  Response.Write("We have a problem with conn")
  Exit Sub
endif
rs.Open "Customers", conn
```

It's not too difficult to move apps from ASP to ASP.net if the apps don't generate a lot of dynamic HTML. Contact me directly and I can discuss this with you.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have a huge 220 pages site and I call ADO at like 400 times ;-( Porting it to ASP.NET would be like 1 year of rewrite ;-(

Comment: Sorry what does it mean, null pointer passed to ADO? I use Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open  "Provider=Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};server=localhost;uid=xxx;pwd=xxx;database=xxx;OPTION=16384;" and then I use: stmt="select..." and Set RS = Conn.Execute(SQLStmt). This works 100 times a second but once every few minutes it crashes ;-( It worked on windows 2012 though.

Comment: Do such "null pointers" passed to ADO accumulate over time and make crash? As most of the requests from users seem to work, site has like 100 users at a time and DB is used heavily...

Comment: One thing you might check on - this has bitten me before - is that you are cleaning up your resources after you've used them. for instance make sure when you have a "Set RS=Conn.Execute..." that you have a corresponding "RS.Close" after you're done with the data.